# AWS Cognito login with Facebook

Tags: javascript, angular, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-facebook

I have an Angular 10 site. I have an AWS Lambda (ASP.NET Core 3.1) that does authentication with AWS Cognito for users with email/password. But I want to allow users to also use Facebook (and eventually Google) to log in as well. In the Facebook/Google scenario my thought is not to allow access to AWS services directly for now (like S3, etc) but to interact with with my other lambda via a bearer token. I have a Cognito User Pool for which I created a Facebook identity provider and mappings. I read somewhere that I'd need an Identity Pool. So I created that and put in my Cognito user pool as a provider as well as Facebook.

Using the JavaScript code:

```
loginWithFacebook = () => {
    const login$ = from(this.facebookService.login());
    login$.subscribe(
      (response: LoginResponse) => {
        console.log(response);
        this.facebookLoginToAWS(response);
      },
      error => {
        console.error(error);
      }
    );
  };
```

I can get a Facebook auth response no problem. Then using this code that you see on every blog, Stack Overflow post, and even in AWS's documentation (of course, substituting my own IdenityPoolId):

```
private facebookLoginToAWS = (facebookResponse: LoginResponse) => {
    console.log('facebookLoginToAWS', facebookResponse);

      if (facebookResponse.status === 'connected' && facebookResponse.authResponse) { 

        AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
          IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-1:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
          Logins: { 'graph.facebook.com': facebookResponse.authResponse.accessToken }
        }, { 
          region: 'eu-west-1'
        });

        AWS.config.credentials.get((err) => {
          if (err) {
            return console.log("Error", err);
          }

          console.log("Cognito credentials", AWS.config.credentials);
          console.log("Cognito Identity Id", AWS.config.credentials.identityId);
        });

      } else if (facebookResponse.status === 'not_authorized') {
        document.getElementById('facebookStatus').innerHTML = 'Please log into this app.';
      } else {
        document.getElementById('facebookStatus').innerHTML = 'Please log into Facebook.';
      }
  };
```

I can get back a session token (in addition to a ton of other stuff like accesKeyId, identityId, and secretAccessKey).

But what do I do with that session token? Perhaps I'm confused, but I would think because there is a mapping between Facebook fields and Cognito fields, that somehow that Facebook user would be migrated into the Cognito user pool and I could get a JWT token for that user for my other lambdas. But after checking the AWS dashboard, I can see a log in (I think) in the Identity Pool but there is no corresponding User Pool entry.

[image]

Do I somehow have to manually migrate it over (using the AWS JavaScript SDK)? I don't want to use the Amplify library. Am I thinking about it wrong? Do I somehow use the session token as a bearer token with my other lambdas? Do I need to add that person as a user pool user somehow?

Comment: You need to follow specific steps to enable Social Identity Providers in Cognito User Pools. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-identity-federation.html. When set up properly, users who sign up with Facebook will be automatically added to the Cognito user pool. Its a good idea to have federated identities as well (Cognito Identity Pool), if you plan on having users access AWS resources.

Comment: Thanks for that. So, I think I have my user pool properly configured. But after reading the documentation, it seems that I have to call the LOGIN endpoint. But what does the body look like? The TOKEN endpoint documentation has body examples. Also, if you look at the TOKEN endpoint docs, they mention the access_code field. But I don't see that. Based on the above code, should I have that somewhere (like in the credentials object)?